# How to change canonical urls for products

Tags: magento-1.9

I have used canonical tags for products. It is taking from root as:

```
    www.example.com/product.html
```

But, I don't want this structure, instead I want the URL to be like this:

```
    www.example.com/category/sub-category/product.html
```

I am not able to find out how can we achieve this, if there is any possibility to do so from back-end or at code-level. Guys, please help me out in here.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible in core Magento and it's not likely to be a quick 'change this' code fix. The canonical tag is the 'one true URL' to the product, and a product can appear in multiple categories. There is no way in core Magento to specify which category will be treated as the 'canonical' category so there is no way to know which one to use in the canonical url.

There are a few SEO extensions around that include this in their feature set. If you wish to perform the task yourself you will need to work out a way/method of prioritising categories, then you can rewrite `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View::_prepareLayout` to modify how it's generating the URL. The simplest approach that springs to mind would be to create an int category attribute for canonical_weight. Then in the above function load a category collection ordered by the attribute and use the first category as part of the URL creation.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way in Magento you can change canonical path in the format you shown above but here is what can be done to achieve the above.

Step 1 - Create primary category attribute (i.e. canonical_primary_category) against the product with the source model as category

Step 2 - Category source model should get all the categories associated with the current product which you getting edited in the admin portal

```
    /**
     * get the list of all categories
     */
    public function getCategories() {
        $categoryOption = array('' => Mage::helper('yourhelper_canonical')->__('Please select primary category'));
        $categoryIds = array();
        $excludedRootCategories = array();

        //if product exists then retrieve only associated categories 
        $product = Mage::registry('current_product');
        if ($product) $categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();

        //getting all the categories for the particular store and sorting them by level and parent_id
        $categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
                            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                            ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('store'))
                            ->addAttributeToSort('level', 'ASC')
                            ->addAttributeToSort('parent_id', 'ASC');

        //if product has categories then load only those categories
        if (!empty($categoryIds)) $categories = $categories->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $categoryIds));

        //load category collection at the end to apply all the above filters
        $categories=$categories->load();

        //loop through loaded categories collection 
        foreach ($categories as $cat):
            //loading collection with all the parent category ids using getPathIds, in simple terms it will load all parent categories associated with this category 
            $collection = $cat->getResourceCollection();
            $collection->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('store'))
                ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $cat->getPathIds()))
                ->addAttributeToSort('level', 'ASC');

            $fullCategoryPath = '';

            //concatenating the whole path using name instead of id 
            foreach ($collection as $col) {
                if (strlen($col->getName())) $fullCategoryPath .= $col->getName().' -> ';
            }
            if ($fullCategoryPath) $fullCategoryPath = substr($fullCategoryPath,0,strlen($fullCategoryPath)-4);

            if (strlen($fullCategoryPath)>0){
                $temp = array('value' => $cat->getId(), 'label' => $fullCategoryPath);
                array_push($categoryOption, $temp);
            }           
        endforeach;

        return $categoryOption;
    }
```

Step 3 - Extract the product URL in the frontend using the following code

```
protected function getProductUrl($product)
    {
        $category_id = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($product->getId(), 'canonical_primary_category', $product->getStoreId());
        if ((int)$category_id>0){
            $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id);
            $url = str_replace('.html','',$category->getUrlPath()).'/'.$product->getUrlPath();
        }
        else{
            $url= $product->getUrlPath();
        }
        return $url;
    }
```

Hope this helps but if you want to spend some bucks instead of creating your own module then the following module will help you achieve this out of the box.

https://www.scommerce-mage.co.uk/magento-canonical-urls-for-category-product-and-cms-pages.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if you have set up category path for the product URL

```
System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Search Engine Optimizations -> Use Categories Path for Product URLs -> Set it to Yes
```

This will add category path to your product urls.

Comment: No, it didn't work out, it just adds the path to the product url not the canonical tag

Answer (score 0):

That is how canonical tags for products should be set. Don't change anything!

If you're not going to have a product in multiple categories you could simply turn off canonical tags for products.